# Strange halo around the Gaussian blur under different viewing angles

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I made a shadow under the box with a Gaussian blur. 
When you look on your mobile it looks good. 
But if you look from the computer monitor at a certain angle, an ugly frame like a halo appears around the shadow.
[image]
What is the matter and how to solve such a problem?

Comment: Why the down and close votes? This is a great question.

Comment: @Vincent Because it's purely a hardware technology issue. It's dependant on the retina technology/model of Macbook and if it has IPS technology or not.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor That comment alone is valuable data for someone who wonders what is wrong with their screen or design program when they see this. I vehemently oppose this question being closed.

Comment: @Vincent Then it should be migrated to another SE.Site

Comment: @Ovaryraptor No. This is relevant to graphic designers.

Comment: @Vincent If the question had more information, specs, and stuff then sure. As it stands this is a camera phone picture of a vector image that is being displayed as a raster. There are too many variables and not enough solid evidence for anyone to find any use from this at all. I can't even begin to format a technical answer because of all of the missing information and lack of access to his set-up.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor Then why don't you ask for those specs rather than voting to close? Besides, Scott seems to do fine on the general approach. I'm sorry if I'm sounding harsh, I don't mean to, but I'm trying to salvage something that, if unanswered or removed, will come back again and again with new designers running into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73055/discussion-between-ovaryraptor-and-vincent).

Comment: @Николай Журенко Nobody will ever view the monitor at that angle. Every display, even the same model from the same factory, is different so you'll just have to remember nobody will ever see the same image you see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the **lighting technology of the monitor**.

There's nothing you can do other than change the screen you are viewing things on or stop looking at it from an angle on that monitor. There's no adjustment you can make to the image itself which will alter the technology of the monitor.

You are essentially asking how to fix your automobile because potholes in the road are making the ride bumpy. You **can't** correct the delivery system by adjusting the object being delivered. That's just how physics works.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can give us details on the file, format, hardware, time of day, pretty much anything and everything we can't help you out. This is highly specific situation where it's really a hardware thing and how light and modern displays work and how your SPECIFIC set-up is.

---

To expand on Scott's answer a little more technically. What you are seeing "COULD" be based on the Pixel Density (ppi, px/cm), Pixel Size (mm), or the Angular pixel density (px/° at typ. distance) or all 3.

Then the viewing distance is a factor too. All displays have a Typical Viewing Distance (typ.) which affects how images are viewed by the human eye.

This all can be used to calculate the PPD or Pixels-Per-Degree.

[image: 2dr(tan(0.5^{\circ })]

> d is the distance to the screen, r is the resolution of the screen in
>   pixels per unit length, and 1° is the aperture of a cone having the apex on
>   focus, height d, and the base in the eye lens

All this equation means is that the aperture varies widely from person to person.

---

All this means is that it's 100% arbitrary and can then also be further complicated by design and even the method of viewing. Is this on Chrome? Firefox? Safari? Each browser has its own method of rendering images.

It could be OLED degradation for all I know.

---

### Final thoughts

Literally nothing I've said should be taken as advice or help, it's purely wild speculation based loosely off of the EXTREMELY limited information given.